# Determine the right cosets of $\langle [3]\rangle$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine the right cosets of $\langle [3]\rangle$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$.

If $$H=\{[3],[6],[9],[0]\},$$

then  $$H+1=\{[4],[7],[10],[1]\}$$

and $$H+2=\{[5],[8],[11],[2]\}$$

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything, but some LaTeX/MathJaX tips: use `\{` and `\}` instead of `{` and `}` for curly brackets, and use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` for angle brackets.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have typed is correct. Well done.

Since $\Bbb Z_{12}$ is abelian, you have also obtained all left cosets, since $a+H=H+a$.